# How to show PDF file without link

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have created a PDF file in my C# code using iTextSharp. This is my code in the view:

```
 <span style="float:left;text-align:left;">            
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Patient" id="hrefCheckedPatients" href="#" onclick="getChecked();">Export to PDF</a>&nbsp;            
                <a href="#" id="lnkPdfDownload" style="display:none;" onclick="$(this).hide();">Download Generated PDF</a>            
</span>...and then:
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/PatientReport/ExportToPDF",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: { uniqueIds: ids },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {                    
                        $('#lnkPdfDownload').show();
                        $('#lnkPdfDownload').attr('href', '/PatientReport/DownloadFile' + '?fName=' + data.fName);
                    } else {
                        $('#lnkPdfDownload').hide();
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#checkedMsg').text('@ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Patient.PatientStrings.CheckedError').show();
                    $('#hrefCheckedPatients').blur();
                }
            });
```

My code in the controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ExportToPDF(List<String> uniqueIds)       {

            //step 1: we create a memory stream that listens to the document
            var output = new MemoryStream();            

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            //Here is the code for generating PDF...
            //The End of ExportToPDF method:
            byte[] byteInfo = output.ToArray();
            output.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
            output.Position = 0;          


            var fName = string.Format("File-{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
            Session[fName] = output;

            return Json(new { success = true, fName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
//And the other method in the controller is here:
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fName)
        {
            var ms = Session[fName] as MemoryStream;
            if (ms == null)
                return new EmptyResult();
            Session[fName] = null;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", fName);
        }
```

So, I generate the report clicking on the button "Export to PDF" , and then I show a link "Download Generated PDF", that the user should click to see the report. I would like to show the report without click on the link, just on button click. How to do that? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an iframe to your html and set the src property of that iframe to the DownloadFile url.

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="" />
                .
                .   
                .
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {                    
                        //maybe show the iframe here on this line
                        $('#myframe').attr('src', '/PatientReport/DownloadFile' + '?fName=' + data.fName);
                    } else {
                        //do something else
                    }

                }
                .
                .
                .
```

Comment: @alenan2013 great, please accept the answer and upvote :)